# how to inherit a Qpushbutton signal

Tags: qt, signals-slots

i passed an argument to a Qt Slot , the argument is a class that i have wroted ( Image_Viewer ).

to make connection betwen a signals and a slots , they both have to had the same type of argument ( correct me if i am wrong ).

i only need the clicked() signal of the Qpushbutton classe but since it has not the same argument of the Slot i have wroted , the connection cant be done.

if making another signal that also have (Image_Viewer) as an argument is the ONLY SOLUTION , then how and where can i wrote it ? and if it isnt then what is the solution ?

PS : Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could  use a [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsignalmapper.html) to simulate "adding" a parameter to the `clicked()` slot. The example in the docs do just that.

More information in the [Signals and Slots - Advanced Usage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html#advanced-signals-and-slots-usage) section.

Answer (score 1):

you can try by using an extra slot to call your slot.

```
connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(slotToCallYourRealSlot()));

void YourClass::slotToCallYourRealSlot()
{
   yourRealSlot(Image_Viewer());
}

void YourClass::yourRealSlot(Image_Viewer viewer)
{
   //your code
}
```